# Updating content in a static Nuxt website

Tags: vue.js, static, nuxt.js

I've built multiple sites with Nuxt SSR, but never touched the static part.

As far as I know, upon build-time, Nuxt automatically executes all API calls and caches them.

If I want to make a blog with a static Nuxt site, how would I update the content? Is it only possible when I rebuild the app?

Seems unnecessary to rebuild everything every time I add a new blog post. With SSR I just reload the page.

Also wanted to note that I have a Strapi.js backend running on a VPS and I usually make changes weekly. [Nuxt's docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/static-site-generation/) state that I need to push my changes to the main repo branch but there's no changes on the frontend.

Does this also mean that the headless cms should be local only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of having a static build is to have all the generated files with no additional server Node.js server needed. It reduces heavily the costs, removes a point of failure, discard any notion of server charge (amount of users at the same time on your app) and probably some other advantages yeah.

Downside, you indeed need to actually `yarn generate` the whole app again if it's something that was added/changed in the codebase. Usually it's pretty fast and there are also incremental builds if I do remember properly (you will not regenerate all the 99 old blog posts but only the 100th, the new one).

Headless CMS like Strapi usually work with a webhook: you add a new CMS article or alike, Strapi will notify your JAMstack platform to rebuild your app. Even if no front-end code was changed, you can force to build it with the new data coming from the headless CMS' API.

Comment: That last part was what I needed.
Still gotta figure out how to do that on my VPS.

Comment: You maybe gonna need to do that manually ib this case. Or just use Netlify or Vercel.